# Получить настройки для камеры из стандартного приложения

Tags: java, android, android-camera

Можно ли как-нибудь получить настройки камеры из стандартного приложения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К камере в Андроид можно обратиться  двумя путями. Первый путь, реализовать функционал работы с камерой в своем приложении. При этом работать придется с экземпляром класса Camera (для подключения к камере),экземпляром класса SurfaceView (для организации предпросмотра). Используя объекты данных классов можно получить доступ и к настройкам камеры.  Второй путь, обратиться при помощи неявного интента к приложению "Камера" и получить от него результат. В том числе и по настройкам.

Comment: Вот интересует второй путь. Как получить из приложения "Камера" настройки.

Comment: в зависимости от API можно воспользоваться либо устаревшим в API 21 классом Camera.Parameters, либо классом CameraCharacteristics

Answer (score 1):

**android.hardware**

*"deprecated"*

```
Camera camera = Camera.open();
camera.getParameters()...;
```

**android.hardware.camera2**

*Added in API level 21*

```
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE);
    manager.getCameraCharacteristics(...);
```

Comment: Есть стандартное приложение в телефоне для фотосъемок, у него уже настроено: вкл./выкл. фотовспышка и другие параметры. В своей программе я получу эти настройки с помощью `camera.getParameters()...;` или получу параметры которые смогу настроить? P.S. Хотелось бы получить именно настройки.